# Replicate mapping in vim inside a function

Tags: vim, neovim

Let's say I have the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>fgr :<C-u>CocCommand fzf-preview.ProjectGrep<Space>
```

Now, let's say instead of directly calling `CocCommand` inside of my mapping, I want to have a function and do the same thing inside of my function.

```
function! MyFunc()
  " what should be here?
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>fgr :call Myfunc()<CR>
```

Is there any way I can achieve this? The key part in the mapping is the `<Space>`, which I don't know how I can do inside of `MyFunc` above

The reason I want to do this is that I've started using [`vim-which-key`](https://github.com/liuchengxu/vim-which-key), where it doesn't allow putting the `<space>` inside of how a *dictionary-mapping* is defined, something like:

```
let g:which_key_mapp = {}
let g:which_key_map['f'] = {
\ 'name': '+fzf',
\ 'g': [ 'call to a function here', 'project grep' ],
\ }
```

I know I can define my mapping and then configure `which-key` to "point" to that mapping, but I was wondering if it's possible to do the thing all inside a function

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to call the function. You're only about to input a few chars.

```
nnoremap <expr><leader>fgr MyFunc()
function! MyFunc() abort
    return ":SomeCommand  SomeArg "
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt for your answer. I updated my question with why I want to do everything inside of a function (for `vim-which-key`), is it possible to do that?